# Show the current 3 months in a dropdown of an MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Months, new List<SelectListItem>{
     new SelectListItem{ Text="June-2018", Value = "June" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="July-2018", Value = "July" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="August-2018", Value = "August" },}, "--Select Month-", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

current month is August so i need only three months in dropdown like above

Comment: You might want to describe what the problem is.

Comment: So in december its eight items, right? ;p

Comment: would you define *current 3 months* ? Did you mean quarter? Current month plus the 2 next or previous ones? months from june 2018 to current month?

Comment: for example , right now its august then i need in dropdown june,july and august only, if current month is may then it would be March , april, may

Comment: @cid you are right, Current month plus the 2  previous ones

Comment: You definitely can't hard code them like you're doing in the dropdown. You'll have to get the previous two months based off the current month in either JavaScrpt/jQuery or c#. C# would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a numeric value for current month using `DateTime.Now.Month`, then substract 1 to get the previous month. If month is 1 (january) the previous month is 12 (december)

```
using System.Globalization;

public int getPreviousMonth(int month)
{
    if (month > 1)
        return (month - 1);
    return (12);
}

DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo(); //System.Globalization

int CurrentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
int PreviousMonth = getPreviousMonth(CurrentMonth);
int PreviousPreviousMonth = getPreviousMonth(PreviousMonth);

Debug.WriteLine(dtfi.GetMonthName(CurrentMonth).ToString()); //August
Debug.WriteLine(dtfi.GetMonthName(PreviousMonth).ToString()); //July
Debug.WriteLine(dtfi.GetMonthName(PreviousPreviousMonth).ToString()); //June
```